# How to fix error "no such scale Error: Failed to release a CodePush update"?

Tags: react-native, react-native-code-push

When pushing a codepush update throught microsoft appcenter it gives the error

> no such scale Error: Failed to release a CodePush update.

this is the command output

> Running "react-native bundle" command:
>   node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --assets-dest
>   /tmp/code-push118719-24926-1rbxzj3.p629/CodePush --bundle-output
>   /tmp/code-push118719-24926-1rbxzj3.p629/CodePush/index.android.bundle
>   --dev false --entry-file index.js --platform android Scanning folders for symlinks in /home/dinuka/dev/lift/passenger-app/node_modules (8ms)
>   Scanning folders for symlinks in
>   /home/dinuka/dev/lift/passenger-app/node_modules (25ms) Loading
>   dependency graph, done.
>  bundle: start bundle: finish bundle: Writing
>   bundle output to:
>   /tmp/code-push118719-24926-1rbxzj3.p629/CodePush/index.android.bundle
>   bundle: Done writing bundle output

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have image assets with @5x or @6x remove them then release build will complete successfully and codepush update will be pushed successfully.